# How to Check Elasticsearch Shipper?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**Status Info:**
we are running elasticsearch 7.5.x version, prety old and no one have information about elasticsearch index setup, we do not have access to the VM's to check directly which log shipper is configured to ship the logs to elasticsearch from MS SQL server.

**Tried Possible Ways:**

1. tried via index template but the configuration is default. even the index pattern name are customize. example: sql.events-*

output:

> { "index": { "codec": "best_compression", "mapping": { "total_fields": { "limit": "500" } }, "number_of_shards": "3", "number_of_replicas": "1" } }

2. tired all the command provide in the elasticsearch doc 7.5 for RestAPI via kibana dev tool.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/rest-apis.html

Q) Is there a way to check via CURL commands to get the information about shipper (either of this filebeat or logstash should ship the logs). check via kibana dev tools? or any other option to identify which shipper inplaced to ship the logs to elasticseach cluster.